# Express JS app processes request multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, extjs

I'm currently creating a app that uses Sencha Ext JS as the front end part and Node JS to handle the user request and data retrieval from MongoDB

When I try to insert data to mongoDB. Ext JS sends a request through ajax. It inserts successfully but when I insert again. It inserts the second request twice.

Here is a snippet of my server.js

```
Server.js

var express = require('express')
var app = express() 
var form = require('formidable')
var document = require('/models/Document.js')


var db = .... //connection to my mongodb instance
app.post('/insertDocument', function(req, res){
    document.insertDocument(req, form, db, function(info){
       return res.end(info) 
    });
});
```

Im using res.end for post request because when I use res.send or res.json when I send a second request it gives me an Error. Cant send headers after they are sent.

```
Document.js
module.exports = {
    insertDocument: function(req, form, db, callback){
        var collection = db.collection('HD_Documents');
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
            collection.insert({
                name: fields.name,
                .
                .
                .
                .
            },function(er, info){
                if(er){
                    callback("{'success':false}");
                }else{
                    callback("{'success':true}")
                }
            })
        })
    }

}
```

Like I said it inserts correctly. But on the second insert request. It inserts the data twice. I checked the network tab in chrome developer tools. And I see that the client only sends one request. But node js server processes it twice.

Im not sure why. Please I need help.
I thought using res.send or res.json would solve the problem but like I said it gives me an error.

Any help would be appreciated. :)

**EDIT**
It turns out the function that was processed twice was the form.parse of formidable.
Im not sure why its still called twice

Comment: This is unrelated, but that's not valid JSON, since JSON uses double quotes for strings and object keys instead of single quotes.

Comment: @mscdex sorry bout the example. My code is at my laptop at work. I just tried to recreate the code the way I remembered it. But i will try to double check it with my code once I get to work tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: @mscdex do you know anyone who could help me with this issue

Answer (score 0):

You just need a res.end() in your last line of callback
Your code should be like this:

```
    module.exports = function foo(req, res) {
        insertDocument: function(req, form, db, callback){
            var collection = db.collection('HD_Documents');
            form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
                collection.insert({
                    name: fields.name,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    .
                },function(er, info){
                    if(er){
                        callback("{'success':false}");
                    }else{
                        callback("{'success':true}")
                    }
                })
                res.end()
            })
        }

    }
```